# How to convert a Flux<DataBuffer> into a StreamingResponseBody in a Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a Flux of DataBuffer in my Spring Controller and I want to attach it to the StreamingResponseBody as a stream. I have read many answers for similar approaches, but nothing quite matches this. I do not want to load the entire file in memory. I want it streamed.

```
@GetMapping(value="/attachment")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> get(@PathVariable long attachmentId) {

    Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer = this.myService.getFile(attachmentId);

    StreamingResponseBody stream = out -> {
       // what do do here?
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .body(stream);
    }
}
```

**EDIT: myService.getFile()**

```
public Flux<DataBuffer> gteFile(long attachmentId) {

    return this.webClient.get()
        .uri("https://{host}/attachments/{attachmentId}", host, attachmentId)
        .attributes(clientRegistrationId("attachmentClient"))
        .accept(MediaType.ALL)
        .exchangeToFlux(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class));
}
```

Comment: why not just return Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>> from controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using WebFlux there's no need to return `StreamingResponseBody`, you can just return `Flux<DataBuffer>` directly, so it will be streaming and also non-blocking.

If you want to add some headers/customize your response, the you can return `Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>>` :

```java
@GetMapping("/attachment/{attachmentId}")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>> get(@PathVariable long attachmentId) {

    Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffers = this.myService.getFile(attachmentId);
    
    ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.inline()
            .filename("example.txt")
            .build();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentDisposition(contentDisposition);

    return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .body(dataBuffers));
}
```

If you want to use `StreamingResponseBody` (which means you're using blocking Spring MVC on web-layer), then you can do the following:

```java
StreamingResponseBody stream = outputStream ->
        Mono.create(sink -> DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffers, outputStream)
                .subscribe(DataBufferUtils::release, sink::error, sink::success)
        ).block();
```

and then return it from your controller

Comment: I tested and it works the first couple times. However, it appears that the DataBuffer memory is not being released.  ERROR io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected  ...  Cannot reserve 4194304 bytes of direct buffer memory

Comment: I've never had the problem you faced, maybe try to add content disposition header with filename, updated my answer. Also, could you show your getFIle() method?

Comment: I've added the getFile() method to the question

Comment: are you using spring mvc in web-layer?

Comment: If you're using Spring MVC, then the error you get in your case is expectable, since your web-layer is blocking. See my updated answer

Comment: @kerbermeister I would add that for spring mvc it may be necessary to update default timeout spring.mvc.async.request-timeout or use WebMvcConfigurer configureAsyncSupport. Otherwise spring may cancel async task sending reaponse before data was fully transmitted.